# Clone clicked div only if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I want to show the entire div.product inside div.cart if the checkbox inside div.product is checked. But since there are multiple div.product on the page i am unable to achieve this. I only want to append the div.product in which the checkbox is checked.

EDIT : Also the div.product should be removed from div.cart if checkbox is unchecked.

So far i have tired many ways including clone():

```
$("input").click(function(){
            $(".product").clone().appendTo(".cart");
        });
```

But to no avail as it clones all div.product inside div.cart as can be seen in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gcomm/xpvt214o/883461/

My Html is as follows, please guide me what mistake am i making. I very new to learning Jquery.

```
<div class="product-list">
<div class="product earrings"> 
<div class=" product-info"> Product 1 </div>
<input type="checkbox" name=" E45" value="1000">
</div>

<div class="product bracelets"> 
<div class=" product-info"> Product 2 </div>
<input type="checkbox" name="E46" value="1000">
</div>

<div class="product rings"> 
<div class=" product-info"> Product 3 </div>
<input type="checkbox" name="E47" value="1000">
</div>
</div>

<div class="cart">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Nothing in the code in the question makes any attempt to check the checkbox or limit the selection to just the `.product` related to that checkbox. 
Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research/searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: When doing your MCVE, a runnable version is very useful, but it should be **here, on-site**, not off-site on jsFiddle. You can use Stack Snippets for that (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really listen out for `change`, instead of `click`. Also, you are not checking if the checkbox is actually checked, but this can be done easily using `this.checked`.

You can also use `parent('.product')` to retrieve the single `.product` element that should be appended.

Below is a demonstration of what you're trying to achieve:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {  
  if( this.checked )
  {
    var $clone = $(this).parent('.product').clone();
    $(this).data('cloned', $clone);
    $clone.appendTo(".cart");
  }
  else if( $(this).data('cloned') )
  {
    $(this).data('cloned').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-list">
  <div class="product earrings"> 
  <div class=" product-info"> Product 1 </div>
  <input type="checkbox" name=" E45" value="1000" />
</div>

<div class="product bracelets"> 
  <div class=" product-info"> Product 2 </div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="E46" value="1000" />
</div>

<div class="product rings"> 
  <div class=" product-info"> Product 3 </div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="E47" value="1000" />
</div>

<div class="cart"></div>
```

Comment: `$(this).is(':checked')` is a long-winded way to write `this.checked`.

Comment: @BenM I see that its working okay. But if the checked box is unchecked items are not removed from div.cart they remain there.

Comment: @Sali I did not see that requirement in your question?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, I know. Updated nevertheless.

Comment: @BenM Updated the question to add this.

Comment: @BenM if the div.product that is cloned inside the div.cart is unchecked it is still not removed. Checkbox has to be unchecked from the div.product-list to be removed.